# Calling activity not returned when back button is pressed

Tags: android-intent

I have three activities - Activity A (Launcher,MAIN), Activity B - Called by Activity A and Activity C (which is the share intent used to share files like images on social networking sites). Activity B calls activity C.

If the user presses the back button in activity C, the activity A is started instead of Activity B. How do I rectify this problem?

I want Activity C should return back to activity B when the "sharing" is cancelled by pressing the back button.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

remove `finish()` when you send `intent` to `activity` C.